# Deletar uma pasta mesmo ela estando com arquivos

Tags: c#, winforms, sintaxe

Qual o código que devo utilizar para apagar uma pasta na qual contenha arquivos dentro da mesma?

Este código que eu utilizei só apaga uma pasta vazia.

```
void ApagarPasta(string nameOf, bool subPastas){
     Directory.Delete(nameOf, subPastas); // Deleta a pasta e subpastas vazias apenas.
}
```

Comment: subPastas é `true`? Precisa ser para deletar recursivamente.

Comment: Não entendi, a resposta resolveu seu problema? Se "resolveu", parece que você não tinha problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro do método `Delete` indica se as sub-pastas/arquivos também devem ser removidos.

```
public static void Delete(
    string path,
    bool recursive
)
```

**path** Tipo: System.String
O nome do diretório a ser removido.

**recursive** Tipo: System.Boolean
true para remover os diretórios, subdiretórios, e os arquivos em path; caso contrário, false.

Exemplo:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete("caminho da pasta", true);
```